Suddenly TransactionPaymentApi_query_info is generating wasm errors at block height 21455372 (maybe runtime 1.2.5?)
I was using the following JSON-RPC method to hit query_info, but suddenly got a wasm error from today. Is this an effect of the runtime update?
If so, what changes are needed?
% curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "payment_queryInfo",
  "params": ["0x4d028400dc79f8c551a63d2e0cae3b48d8f5546a01519435547549e2ddafff03db69d6b802ef7e99d4c10478bd1eeb7c25fa8f67f803bb29c749a433e60b63afa49c9cb508505385adb52faff90c06d9d7df23084a86f3c73b039c575d9d93f648e0c76c12019500590f000500005b319adeae0b1813e257ee19b008ee502bc759583ed4fe7ddaf7427afd7c0dac0b88779361c812", "0xfefca3ef82ad35f84cf3fcaaf6dccb2768a3050de00d40821a03e06df2a418f1"],
  "id": 1
}' https://rpc.polkadot.io
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":1,"message":"Unable to query dispatch info.","data":"Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed\nWASM backtrace:\nerror while executing at wasm backtrace:\n    0: 0x63a3 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind\n    1: 0x2eb7 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::hbb5a6b42001bdfec\n    2: 0x53ea58 - <unknown>!TransactionPaymentApi_query_info"},"id":1}


There is a new signed extension that should be included in the transaction. Most likely, its absence is the reason you are getting that error. https://github.com/polkadot-fellows/runtimes/pull/337
